# Need to iterate through <select> options and simulate a click on each one so I can scrape data from a preview div

Tags: javascript

I'm building a chrome extension that locates different elements in a servicenow ticket and scrapes the selected items and copies the information to the clipboard.  I'm almost done with the project, but I'm running into one issue.  When selecting users for a request, the user will choose either a single, or multiple selections from the 'available users' list, and those users get placed in the 'selected users' list.  Unfortunately, the information that goes to the selected users list is just the first and last name, which isn't necessarily a unique identifier.  However, if you click once on an entry in the selected users list, preview information will display for that user, and the users email address is included in that info.  I'm trying to programmatically move through the selected users list and simulate a click on a user, then scrape the email address from the preview section and add it to an array, then move to the next user in the list, simulate a click, scrape the email for that user, add it to the array and so on.

I've been able to create a function that goes through the options in the selected users list, and it selects each user one at a time, and I can see on the screen that the preview information is changing rapidly from user to user.  The problem I'm running into is that when it scrapes the email address from the preview section, its always getting the information for just one of the users.  I'm not sure if its a timing issue, or if I'm missing something in my approach.

Here's the segment of my code that tries to go through the options in the selected user list, click on them one at a time, and scrape the email address from the preview section:

```js
var users1 = tr4.querySelector('[class^="slushbucket-top is-prefilled"]');

var alloptions = tr4.querySelector(
    '[id^="list_of_the_staff_members_select_0"]'
);

var users = users1.querySelector("select");
var users2 = users1.querySelectorAll("option");
console.log(users2);
var seluserlist = [];

function triggerChange(element) {
    let changeEvent = new Event("change");

    element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
}

var numofselected = users2.length;

for (let m = 0; m < numofselected - 1; m++) {
    console.log(users2.length);
    console.log(alloptions);
    console.log(users.length);

    if (m > 0) {
        users2[m - 1].selected = false;
    }

    users2[m].selected = true;
    users2[m].ariaSelected = true;
    users2[m].focus;
    users2[m].click;
    var siu = tr4.querySelector('[id^="list_of_the_staff_membersrecordpreview"]');

    triggerChange(users);
    triggerChange(users1);
    triggerChange(tr7);
    triggerChange(siu);

    console.log(users2[m].value);
    console.log(users[m].value);
    console.log(siu.innerText);

    var tempvar = siu.querySelectorAll("option");
    console.log(tempvar);

    seluserlist[m] = siu.innerText + ";";
    allprevs.focus;

    users2[m].selected = false;
    users2[m].ariaSelected = false;
    users[m].selected = false;
    users[m].ariaSelected = false;
    users.focus;
}

console.log(seluserlist);

var singleuserinfo = tr4.querySelectorAll(
    '[id^="list_of_the_staff_membersrecordpreview"]'
);

var allsuinodes = singleuserinfo.childNodes;

console.log(singleuserinfo);
console.log(users2);
console.log(users.selectedOptions.length);

var tr8 = tr7.querySelector("select");
var numbersnode = tr8.querySelectorAll("option");
var singlenumbernode = tr8.querySelector("option");
var tr9 = users.querySelectorAll("option");
var cn = tr9.childNodes;

console.log(tr9);
console.log(numbersnode);
console.log(singlenumbernode);
console.log(cn);

var allnames = "";

for (let k = 0; k < tr9.length; k++) {
    allnames = allnames + tr9[k].innerText + ";";
}

console.log(allnames); //above function iterates through all selected usernames and puts them in the 'allnames' string

var cleannames1 = allnames;
var cleannames2 = cleannames1.split(";");

for (let q = 0; q < cleannames2.length - 1; q++) {
    var fandlnames = cleannames2[q].split(" ");
    cleannames2[q] = fandlnames[1] + "," + fandlnames[0];
}

console.log(cleannames2);
console.log(numbersnode);
```

Comment: It is likely a timing issue. You can use a setInterval to test if the element is filled

Comment: Is the text within the `<div>` determined by the `.value` of the `<select>` or by another source?

Comment: I'll see if I can make any progress using setinterval.  The strange thing is that I can run the code on the exact same page multiple times in succession, and sometimes the preview information will all be for one selected user, but then another time, it will all be for a different selected user.

Also, as far as I know the text within the div is generated by a function that runs when you click on a user entry in the selected users list.  I think when you click an entry for a user it runs the value for the user (their SN GUID) through the function and returns the corresponding email address

Comment: I wonder if this can be simplified to just setting the `.selectedIndex` for every index in the list (0 to length-1)?

Comment: `document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = i` should work in a loop. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76930944/2813224) where the equivalent of  `document.querySelector("select").options[i].selected = "selected"` is used.

Comment: Just to clarify, the part of my code where I'm changing the clicked on user in the select field is already working fine.  I added a console log line after changing the selected option to see exactly what the value was for the selected option, and I can see that the selected value is changing like it should.  The problem is that after that value changes, the preview area gets its information updated, but when I try to save that info to a variable, the info that it gives me isn't for the currently selected user, its typically for either the first, or last user on the list of selected users.

Comment: Are you trying to get the info in the `<div>`  as the `<select>` is programmatically iterated through it's `<option>`s?

Comment: You should post the actual code responsible for the setting data in the `<div>` when the `<select>` is changed and the HTML as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @user2312463 Added another example that uses an external data source that might be closer to what you need (without the information previously requested, any solution would still be based on guesses).

Answer (score 0):

## `<option>`

The way data is handled differs on whether the `<option>`s have a `.value` or not.

- If an `<option>` has a `.value`, the `.value` of `<select>` will be the `.value` of the selected `<option>`:

  ```
  <select>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="X" selected>10</option> 
  </select>
  let result = select.value; // "X";
  ```
- To access the text of the selected `<option>` that has a `.value`:

  ```
  <select>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="X" selected>10</option> 
  </select>
  let selectedOpt = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  let result = selectedOpt.textContent; // "10"
  ```
- If an `<option>` ***does not*** have a `.value`, then the `<select>` `.value` will be the text of said selected `<option>`:

  ```
   <option selected>10</option>
   let result = select.value; // "10"
  ```

In **Example A**, there are 2 `<select>`s: `select#A` has `<option>`s with `.value` and `select#B` has `<option>`s without `.value`.

In **Example B**, `showData(array, select, output)` is used to find the user in an array of objects that corresponds to the `.value` of the `<select>` and display the user `.email` property in the given `output` element (`<fieldset>`).

**Details are commented in example**

<sup>Note: `<fieldset>` is used instead of `<div>` for aesthetic purposes only.</sup>

### Example A

```js
// Reference <select> that has <option>s with .value.
const selA = document.getElementById("A");
// Reference <select> that has <option>s without .value.
const selB = document.getElementById("B");
// Reference <fieldset>.
const box = document.querySelector("fieldset");

// Pass in references for <select> and <fieldset>.
function setOption(select, output) {
  // Define an empty array.
  let results = [];
  // Collect all <option>s of <select> into a HTMLCollection.
  const opts = select.options;
  // Iterate through the HTMLCollection "opts".
  for (let i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    // Set .selected property on current <option>.
    opts[i].selected = "selected";
    // Set <fieldset> text to the .value of <select>.
    output.textContent = select.value;
    // Add text of <fieldset> to array "results".
    results.push(output.textContent);
  }
  // Return array "results" after the loop is complete.
  return results;
}

/** 
 * If the text of <fieldset> is determined by the text of
 * the selected <option> and it has a .value:
 *   ex. <option value="2">III</option>
 * replace the next line with the following:
 *   output.textContent = opts[i].textContent;
 * If there is a function that determines the text of <fieldset>
 * replace the next line with the function call:
 *   ex. functionName(); 
 */
console.log(JSON.stringify(setOption(selA, box)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(setOption(selB, box)));

/**
 * For demo purposes.
 * When the .value changes on <select>, the text of <fieldset>
 * will be the .value of <select>.
 */
selA.onclick = e => box.textContent = e.target.value;
selB.oninput = e => box.textContent = e.target.value;
```

```css
select { width: 10ch; font: inherit; text-align: center; }

fieldset { width: 8ch; margin-top: 4px; padding: 4px; text-align: center; }

.as-console-row { visibility: collapse; }

.as-console-row:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<select id="A">
  <option value="1">I</option>
  <option value="2">II</option>
  <option value="3">III</option>
  <option value="4">IV</option>
</select>

<select id="B">
  <option>I</option>
  <option>II</option>
  <option>III</option>
  <option>IV</option>
</select>

<fieldset></fieldset>
```

### Example B

```js
const data = [{
  "id": "7cc6d6c9-3673-4ae9-a485-381346bd89f5",
  "name": "Abagael Tommen",
  "email": "atommen0@deviantart.com"
}, {
  "id": "bed46317-a487-40f0-9af3-0d52e990b63f",
  "name": "Wenona Oldford",
  "email": "woldford1@joomla.org"
}, {
  "id": "a969f4f3-32c7-4021-97bd-6e2512d9ba46",
  "name": "Vania Bremond",
  "email": "vbremond2@blogspot.com"
}, {
  "id": "fa33589f-5876-4999-9f9d-b91cc0cc89d8",
  "name": "Sayre Tedahl",
  "email": "stedahl3@google.ru"
}];

const sel = document.querySelector("select");
const box = document.querySelector("fieldset");

function setOptions(array, select) {
  array.forEach(user => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = user.id;
    option.text = user.name;
    select.add(option);
  });
}

function showData(array, select, output) {
  const users = array.filter(user => user.id === select.value);
  output.textContent = users[0].email;
}

function scrapeEmails(array, select, output) {
  let results = [];
  const opts = select.options;
  for (let i=0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    opts[i].selected = "selected";
    showData(array, select, output);
    results.push(output.textContent);
  }
  return results;
}  

setOptions(data, sel);

sel.oninput = e => showData(data, sel, box);

console.log(scrapeEmails(data, sel, box));
```

```css
select { width: 26ch; font: inherit; text-align: center; }

fieldset { width: 24ch; margin-top: 4px; padding: 4px; text-align: center; }

.as-console-row { visibility: collapse; }

.as-console-row:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<select></select>
<fieldset></fieldset>

<!--
  After setOptions(data, sel, box) runs, <select> will have <option>s":
  ex.
  <select>
    <option value="7cc6d6c9-3673-4ae9-a485-381346bd89f5">
      Abagael Tommen
    </option>
    <option value="bed46317-a487-40f0-9af3-0d52e990b63f">
      Wenona Oldford
    </option>
    ...
  </select>
-->
```

Comment: Just wanted to give an update after working on this more today.  I think the issue may be that the click events I'm using for selecting a user to load the preview information aren't considered 'trusted'.  I added alerts to my code to put stops in place to see exactly what its doing and when, and I noticed that while it loops and changes the selected items, those changes aren't reflected on the webpage until AFTER the entire script has finished running.

Comment: In both examples the function (**Example A** `setOption()` and **Example B** `scrapeEmails()`) that iterates and gathers the data in the `<fieldset>` runs alone and is not an event handler (a function that's called when an event such as "click" is fired). So in short, if you want to manipulate an element programmatically, do not bind the function as an event handler.